# Print same barcode multiple times in report

Tags: jasper-reports, barcode

I want to print an *JasperReports* report with bar code. What I need is the user to send one bar code (example "ABCDERDIA") and a number , say 50

the output should be the bar code for "ABCDERDIA" 50 times, in 4 columns (one next to the other).

any ideas how can i get something as simple as this?

edit: I add - its always the SAME barcode to be printed each time, and it works ok if it need 150 times the bar code , then i create a datasource of 150 elements which are the same. but since is the SAME code each time, i want to send it once and iterate to the number for more efficiency

Answer (score 0):

Depending on you DB the "generate series" works in Oracle it would be

```
SELECT 'ABCDERDIA' as barcode
FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 50
```

make this your Query 
based on your edit i think it would be something like

```
SELECT 'ABCDERDIA'||rownum as barcode
FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 50
```

or to make it reusable create a prompt for the of time to repeat

```
SELECT 'ABCDERDIA'||rownum as barcode
FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM < $P{repeat_nbr}
```